# Don't understand how using zip(*) un-zips the data

Tags: python, python-3.x

Transpose data from a 4-by-3 matrix to a 3-by-4 matrix:

```
data = ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11))
data_transpose = tuple(zip(*data))

print(data_transpose)
```

The output is:

```
((0, 3, 6, 9), (1, 4, 7, 10), (2, 5, 8, 11))
```

I don't understand why it did this behavior.

I know if I loop for the same data I can get the index if I use `zip(* data)`
but the one line `tuple(zip(*data))`. I don't understand how the output became 3 by 4 matrix.

Comment: You don't nuderstand the star * ? or the ues of `tuple` ?

Comment: Work through what you understand by hand

Comment: @martineau what i didn't understand is where the first tuple in the list went as long as the start is letting me use the index

Comment: In a nutshell, I guess to point you need to understand is that `zip(*data)` is merely shorthand for `zip((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11))`, so `zip` returns 3 groups of 4 items each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zip` method aggregates elements from each of the iterables, with the star operator allows to pass each tuple (of 3) as a separator agument

```
zip(*data)
# does : 
zip((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11))
```

So it aggregates them by index

```
  index --> 0  1  2
            |  |  |
            v  v  v
1st param : 0  1  2
2nd param : 3  4  5
3rd param : 6  7  8
4th param : 9 10 11
```

Makes 3 tuple of 4, by column regarding the previous drawing

```
index
    0  (0, 3, 6, 9)
    1  (1, 4, 7, 10)
    2  (2, 5, 8, 11)
```

And as `zip` outputs a iterator, you need a method that'll read it, for example list or tuple

```
data_transpose = tuple(zip(*data))
print(data_transpose)  # ((0, 3, 6, 9), (1, 4, 7, 10), (2, 5, 8, 11))

data_transpose = list(zip(*data))
print(data_transpose)  # [(0, 3, 6, 9), (1, 4, 7, 10), (2, 5, 8, 11)]
```

Answer (score 0):

> The purpose of Python `zip()` method is to map the similar index of multiple containers so that they can be used just using as single entity.

In your code:

```
data = ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11))
```

It does the following:
So, there are 3 values

```
(0,3,6,9)
(1,4,7,10)
(2,5,8,111)
```

You are unpacking the tuple using `*`. So, all the elements are passed in `zip()`.

Linking the logic:

> `tuple()`:  This function accepts a single parameter iterable (optional). It is an iterable(list, range etc..)

> `zip`: Returns a single iterator object, having mapped values from all the containers.

So, it is converting the whole returned value into a tuple.